"Штабелируемость груза" или "Возможность штабелирования груза" или "Штабелирование"?
Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать:

"Штабелируемость /груза/ - 25 уровней"
"Возможность штабелирования /груза/ - 25 уровней"
"[Допустимое] Штабелирование /груза/ - 25 уровней"?

Не могу найти слово "Штабелируемость" в словарях и даже в тех. документации более-менее приличной.
Нужно в форме грамотно указать название поля, где будет указано число уровней для штабелирования, допустимых для указанного груза.
Важно написать коротко (это название поля).
Благодарю!

ГОСТ 16299-78: Упаковывание. Термины и определения:
Штабелирование продукции (тары) -

D. Pallettieren von Erzeugnissen
E. Product units stacking
F. Empilage du produit
Группирование продукции (тары), выполненное в вертикальном направлении

Штабель -

3.1.4 штабель : Ровно расположенный ряд чего-либо (например, конструктивных элементов, шпал).

Я бы написал: максимально допустимая высота штабелирования груза при складировании/перевозке - 25 штабелей(уровней).
Термин употребить наверное нужно, но так как вы его не знаете, те кто будете читать инструкцию также могут не знать, лучше пояснить, мне кажется, чтобы потом не было непоняток. Если это важный пункт, можно выделить дополнительно.

Спасибо за ответ и за ссылку на ГОСТ!
Думаю, что коверкать языка я точно не хочу, поэтому - "Штабелирование" будем использовать. Длинный предложенный вариант не получится, так как это в форме и там нет возможности писать много слов. Благодарю!
